# How to use an excel cell value as a cell name and put data there?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns of data. On column has cell names (B63, J63, P63...) the other column has values. I'd like a way to put each value listed in the adjacent named cell.

Example: Cell A1 contains B63. Cell B1 contains 1.08274. I'd like to write a macro that will assign 1.08274 to B63.

The column is several hundred entries long and I don't want to do this by hand. Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: I am a self taught VBA user and don't know the syntax to do most of what i want to. I got stuck getting vba to just do the Range(addy) operation below. I don't think i defined the variable correctly.

Comment: We don't mind if you're new, learning, self taught, etc.  We simply want to see that you have at least put in some effort and aren't just asking others to do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, L As Long, addy As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For L = 1 To N
        addy = Cells(L, 1).Value
        Range(addy).Value = Cells(L, 2).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

To get both the value & the format, we will do a genuine copy:

```
Sub sequel()
    Dim N As Long, L As Long, addy As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For L = 1 To N
        addy = Cells(L, 1).Value
        Cells(L, 2).Copy Range(addy)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a champ. Any way to also copy over the cell formatting?

Comment: Thanks, this was insanely helpful.